# Can we encode 2 dimension number into one number for sorting

Tags: binary, numbers, geospatial

To put it bluntly. I use a database that can only have 1 column for sort and filter; Amazon DynamoDB; and I want to develop geospatial query with it

So I have latitude and longitude. And I want to do it like this

First, make it 0,0 coordinate

Second, make it integer `(floor(lat|long * 65535 / 360))`

Third separate both into bit. And reorder it so latitude bit and longitude bit next to each other

such as it is latitude 0011 and longitude 0101 it would become 00101011

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

65535 is 16 bit so it became 32 bit int and stored in database

So when I query I could do it like this

`query BETWEEN (left|top , right|bottom)`

Where `left|top` and `right|bottom` is the same lat|long encoding above

I'm not sure I misunderstand something. Is it really possible to make this scope an area of 2D plane with just 1D number? Or I just overlook a problem

Comment: You've describe the basic algorithm of the Geohash, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Comment: @cffk I want to promote your comment as answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

You need a [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) or other Location Code system (see for example [Open location Code](http://openlocationcode.com/)). Both of these approaches allow you to store better than integer precision and still allow bounding box searches to occur quickly.